# Git push whole branch instead of changes only

Tags: git

Whenever I push forcelly, whole branch is pushed instead of changes only

git push origin branch -f

Comment: So ? That is what it's for.

Comment: Sorry I did not get your point

Comment: Force push overwrites the remote one.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: Voted to close as needing clarity because there's no question here, it's just a statement of git's behavior. If you're wondering how to get different behavior, please ask that, including a description of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your `force push` your local branch, in order to overwrite the remote one.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

By design, git only sends/downloads changesets that aren't present at the receiving end. It complains if you try to push changes that aren't a fast-forward (i.e., don't follow after the last chageset over there, you amended something locally after pushing it). To push them anyway, you `--force` (or `-f`) the push. The idea is that the whole history is present at each user's machine (there are ways to get just a part of the history, but that isn't common usage).